# «Маслосыроварен(н)ый творог». Одна или две «н»?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно? По идее, нужна одна, так как это просто сложное причастие, а в слове *вареный* — одна *н*. Но в ПАС написанно почему-то с двумя (в начале): http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=37#pp37.

`Маслосыровареный творог.`

`Маслосыроваренный творог.`

Comment: что такое маслосыроваренный? Масло не варят) что за чепуха

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно, действительно, с **двумя Н**:

***Маслосыроваренный творог***.

И хотя кажется, что это отглагольное прилагательное, образованное от глагола *варить*, всë совсем не так.

Дело в том, что подобные слова, напр.: *пивоваренный*, *мыловаренный*, *клееваренный*, *сыроваренный* и т. д. — образованы от **существительных**, а не от глаголов. Такие слова являются обычными прилагательными, а не отглагольными, т. к. образованы от существительных: *пивоварня*, *мыловарня*, *сыроварня*, *маслосыроварня*.

Такие прилагательные не имеют глагольного значения.

---

А две Н здесь потому, что прилагательное образовано суффиксом **-ЕНН-**:

*Маслосыровар**енн**ый*.

В остальных случаях тоже -ЕНН-, поэтому используем две.

Опять же, это прилагательное отглагольным не является, оно является отыменным, поэтому ориентируемся на суффиксы, с помощью которых они образованы, а не на глагол.